# Получить список IP-адресов устройств локальной сети (Android, Java)

Tags: java, android, сеть

Моё андроид-приложение *(клиент)* устанавливает соединение с компьютером *(сервером)* средствами сетевых сокетов по протоколу **TCP-IP**. И мне нужно получить список IP-адресов устройств (или более подробную информацию: название устройста, MAC и т.д., желательно компьютеров) в локальной сети, будь то **WIFI**, **HotSpot** и т.д средствами *Java*.

Каким образом я могу это сделать? Буду очень признателен.

---

*Заранее спасибо!))*